# Status of undocumented Open Graph calls?

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

I would like to be able to use the data that is provided by the following Insights call:

page_id/insights/page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique

Unfortunately, this particular call is not mentioned anywhere in Facebook's documentation, and after an extensive web search, I can't find a reference to it anywhere. I can tell you that Facebook's own Insights GUI makes use of this information.

Does anyone know the status of this call? I would like to know if it is deprecated before I created something that relies on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ there's a report documentation error.  You should report it using that button.

Answer (score 0):

This new metric is new and also available in the new Facebook Insights. So I think it's pretty safe to use it for now.